# Integration of Fourier series produces denominator of $0$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, exponential-function, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I want to explore the integral of the Fourier series for an impulse train:

$$\sum_{k=0}^R \frac{e^\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}}{R+1}$$

where $i=\sqrt(-1)$.

I find

$$\int \sum_{k=0}^R \frac{e^\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}}{R+1}=-\sum_{k=0}^R i \frac{e^\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}}{2 k \pi}$$

But this is not mathematically useful because of the $k$ in the denominator.

The curve quite clearly has a finite (and presumably therefore definable) area beneath both its real component and $-i$ times its imaginary component. For example, $R=3$ gives the following real (first) and imaginary (second) curves:

[image: Real component]

[image: Imaginary component]

Integrating real and imaginary components separately doesn't help, I still end up with a denominator of $0$.

Can anyone help or explain?

Comment: for $k=0$, the $\exp(k \cdot \text{something})=1$, so it'd be good to treat it separately.

Comment: So you suggest I say $\sum_{k=0}^R \frac{e^ \frac{2ik \pi x}{R+1}}{R+1}=\frac{1}{R+1}+\sum_{k=1}^R \frac{e^ \frac{2ik \pi x}{R+1}}{R+1}$ and then integrate from there?

Comment: Yes, you should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have that
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^R \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}\right)}{R+1}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{R+1}+\sum_{k=1}^R \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}\right)}{R+1}$$
Because $e^0=1$. You should integrate this one:
$$\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{1}{R+1}+\sum_{k=1}^R \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}\right)}{R+1} \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\frac{x}{R+1} + \sum_{k=1}^R\exp\left(\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}\right) \frac{1}{R+1} \frac{1}{\frac{2 i k \pi}{R+1}}$$
$$\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\frac{x}{R+1} + \sum_{k=1}^R\exp\left(\frac{2 i k \pi x}{R+1}\right) \frac{1}{2ik \pi}$$
So the problem was that you were dividing by $0$. I think it's a common source of problems in the fourier analysis, it can appear when you are calculating the fourier coefficients as well.